# ActionView::Template::Error - no route matches (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and faced this problem.

I pushed my app to heroku, made 1 test entry in production and then after that made changes - added in 2 gems to replace previous controller actions and pushed to git and heroku.

It is at this point that my app in production mode breaks, displaying the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error - no route matches
```

On my initial test entry. I think I should drop the previous database in heroku and run rake db:migrate again but I am not sure exactly how to go about it (I am not that familiar with heroku just yet). Any pointers and guidance much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using SQLite3 in development and PG in production. There are no issues when i run it in my local environment

Answer (score 0):

For your current problem:

- did you commit and push all changes?
- does this work locally?
- have migrations been run on Heroku? (`$ heroku run rake db:migrate:status` will tell you)

To drop the current database on Heroku, use `pg:reset`:

```
$ heroku pg:reset --app <app_name>
```

You can then re-run your migrations:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app <app_name>
```

Comment: hi catsby, everything runs ok in my local environment. the only issue is with heroku. i tried your suggestion however with heroku pg:reset DATABASE as that was what heroku prompted me to do and ran rake db:migrate again after dropping the database but unfortunately when i open the app, it just says "the page does not exist". I checked the logs, it nows finds an error with User id 3 not existing. I thought these issues would be solved by dropping the database?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally figured it out. Everything i tried (resetting the database on heroku etc) didn't work, so i deleted the cookies manually and voila everything worked. It was due to the fact that i did not 'log out' my previous test user on heroku so it was throwing an error that the 'user id did not exist'.